# Grouping by time interval in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that imports with 2 columns (Time, Heart Rate).

The time comes in with the format MM:SS.s (for minutes:Seconds.miliseconds). I am trying to convert this time into a float of seconds (e.g. 0.6s or 65.3s) (to later be used to collapse into 10s windows). For example:

```
import pandas as pd
hr_raw = pd.read_csv('hr_data.csv')
hr_raw.dropna(inplace=True)
print(hr_raw.head())

   Time       HR bpm
0  00:00.6    97.0
1  00:01.0    92.0
2  00:01.3    80.0
3  00:01.6    81.0
4  00:02.0    80.0
```

Previously (when importing using the standard CSV module) I just split this string, converted to a float and did the math to convert it to seconds:

```
 with open('hr_data.csv', 'rU') as infile:
     hr_data = list(csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=','))
     for row in hr_data:
         temp = row['Time']
         time.append(float(temp[3:7]) + (float(temp[0:2]) * 60))
```

Now that I am using a pandas df the code isn't working. I've tried to modify so that I am accessing the 'Time' column (see below), but not having much luck.

```
import pandas as pd

win_size = 10  # user defined window in seconds

hr_raw = pd.read_csv('hr_data.csv')
hr_raw.dropna(inplace=True) #remove NaN artifact from import

#### problem code ####
for row in hr_raw.Time:
    hr_raw.Time[row] = float(hr_raw.Time[row][3:]) + float((hr_raw.Time[row][0:2] * 60))

# set time as index
hr_raw.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

# bin data based on user defined window
hr_bin = hr_raw.groupby((hr_raw.index // win_size + 1) * win_size).mean()
```

The error that comes up is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5126)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 759, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:14010)
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mitbl001\Dropbox\CPET_python\import_hr_csv.py", line 11, in <module>
    hr_raw.Time[row] = float(hr_raw.Time[row][3:]) + float((hr_raw.Time[row][0:2] * 60))
  File "C:\Users\mitbl001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\mitbl001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2477, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\_libs\index.c:4404)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\_libs\index.c:4087)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 156, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5210)
KeyError: '00:00.6'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your time column to float using `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df.Time).dt.total_seconds()
df

   Time  HR bpm
0   0.6    97.0
1   1.0    92.0
2   1.3    80.0
3   1.6    81.0
4   2.0    80.0
```

---

A `groupby` should be simple now using the syntax:

```
df.groupby(df.Time // x * x)
```

Where `x` is your desired window of time. Here's an example of grouping in intervals of 0.5 seconds and taking the mean of the heart rate:

```
df.groupby(df.Time // 0.5 * 0.5)['HR bpm'].mean()

Time
0.5    97.0
1.0    86.0
1.5    81.0
2.0    80.0
Name: HR bpm, dtype: float64
```

The above outputs a series. If you want to obtain a dataframe, you can call `reset_index` after the groupby.

```
df.groupby(df.Time // 0.5 * 0.5)['HR bpm'].mean().reset_index()

   Time  HR bpm
0   0.5    97.0
1   1.0    86.0
2   1.5    81.0
3   2.0    80.0
```

In your case, you'd do something along the lines of `df.groupby(df.Time // 10 * 10)`.

Comment: Thanks @COLDSPEED ! Just so I can get my head around this - what is the difference between the df I originally had (i.e. 2 columns; time, heartrate) and the df that comes out after the .groupby command (index of time and 1 column of heart rate but no heading)?

Comment: @Braden The output is a series, with `Time` as the index. If you want to return a dataframe, you can use: `df.groupby(df.Time // 0.5 * 0.5, as_index=False)['HR bpm'].mean()`. But it's basically the same thing.

Comment: @Braden Edited so you can see. Actually you should use `reset_index` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) with cast to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
hr_raw.Time = hr_raw.Time.str[3:].astype(float) + hr_raw.Time.str[0:2].astype(float) * 60
print (hr_raw)

   Time  HR bpm
0   0.6    97.0
1   1.0    92.0
2   1.3    80.0
3   1.6    81.0
4   2.0    80.0
```

Another solution is converting [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), but before add from right side `hour`s by [`radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.radd.html):

```
hr_raw.Time = pd.to_timedelta(hr_raw.Time.radd('00:')).dt.total_seconds()
print (hr_raw)

   Time  HR bpm
0   0.6    97.0
1   1.0    92.0
2   1.3    80.0
3   1.6    81.0
4   2.0    80.0
```

And then set_index is not necessary, use column `Time`:

```
# bin data based on user defined window
hr_bin = hr_raw.groupby((hr_raw.Time // win_size + 1) * win_size).mean()
print (hr_bin)
      Time  HR bpm
Time              
10.0   1.3    86.0
```

Comment: I see you've edited your answer to add something that looks a LOT like the second part of my answer.

Comment: You really think `df.groupby(df.Time // 0.5 * 0.5)['HR bpm'].mean()` and `hr_raw.groupby((hr_raw.Time // win_size + 1) * win_size).mean()` are different, besides the variable names?

Comment: Only the index changes, the aggregated values remain the same. If you do +1, your index will start with 10. Otherwise, start at 0. Agg'd values remain the same.

Comment: It's your post... I can't tell you what to do. :-)